# categorization of $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

There are three types of Von Neumann algebras,namely,Type $I,II,III$ VNA .I wonder whether the $C^*$ algebra can be categorized completely?

Comment: Categorization is very misleading term (not related to category theory). It is better to say classification. Plus, you need to specify what do you mean by "completely". Factors are not classified up to isomorphism by their type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to be more careful on what do you mean by categorize. $C^\ast$-algebras include locally compact topological spaces whose classification by homeomorphism is undecidable. Indeed, just differentiable manifolds of dimension higher than $5$ are unclassifiable (in the sense that its classification problem would be equivalent to the Halting problem).

That result follows from the fact that finitely presented groups have a non-decidable isomorphism problem and, using a surgery-like procedure, it is possible to construct 5-manifolds with any given finitely presented group as fundamental group [Ma].

Nevertheless there is a "classification program" for nuclear, separable and simple $C^\ast$ algebras (if you will, the $C^\ast$-algebra version of hyperfinite factors) using $K$ theory.

[Ma] *Markov, A.*, The insolubility of the problem of homeomorphy, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 121, 218-220 (1958). [ZBL0092.00702](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0092.00702).